# How does recursive division to generate maze work?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, logic, maze

So ive been wanting to generate a perfect maze! So i wanted to use the recursive divison algorithm. However, I dont really get how the algorithm will generate a perfect maze, i dont know what im missing, but here is my doubt:

Algorithm:

1. Begin with an empty field.
2. Bisect the field with a wall, either
   horizontally or vertically.
3. Add a single passage through the wall.
4. Repeat step #2 with the areas on either side of the wall. Continue,
   recursively, until the maze reaches the desired resolution.

My doubt:

1. Suppose lets say its a 10*10 gird, indexed from 0.
2. Lets say the algorithm randomly decided to make an horizontal cut at 6th row, leaving a passage through the 7th column
3. Now when I recurse on the top and bottom parts of the grid, let us assume top for simplicity. If in the top part i choose the 5th row and build a passage through, say, 2nd column.
4. I have effectively now drawn two rows in the 5th and 6th row, disconnecting the top and bottom halves. Hence my maze is not perfect!! right?

Some one help me understand what i'm missing here?

Comment: Can you draw a diagram showing your problem? You've probably made a mistake somewhere, but it's hard to tell without seeing what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I guess your "walls" have thickness (eg: 1 grid square) rather than on the edges between grid squares.

Comment: @r3mainer Thanks a lot!!! That link was my exact problem as well!! Now i know what to do

Comment: @PaulHankin my aplogies, for not explaining properly, but i was able to ind the same doubt answered else where! so i guess the problem is solved now! thanks a lot